# How to make email submit form hide "form action=bla-bla.php" part from bots?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, html-email, spam-prevention

I have bot/fake emails being submitted to my email list every day even though they don't show up in my landing page google analytics statistics where my email submit form is. I was told that the bots are bypassing the form probably, sending POST requests straight to the URL where the form is submitted.

```
<form action="http://example.com/something.php">
```

They go straight to something.php and submit.

I was told that I could either make a javascript that submits the form onclick (so the form doesn't show the action stuff) or through some modifications to the PHP script that is processing the form.

I have no idea how to do that. Can you help me?

The original bare bones form code:

```
<form action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey w3-text-blue w3-margin">

  <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="email" input type="email" required placeholder="Enter Your Email Here">
  <input type="hidden" name="campaign_token" value="fhdfh" />
  <input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="https://example.com/confirm-email.php"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="start_day" value="0" />
</div>

<div style="margin-top:25px;"><button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-block w3-section w3-deep-orange w3-ripple" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Send me the eBook on Email</button></div>

</form>
```

Comment: What you probably want is a captcha, something to verify the client submitting the form. Feels to me like [google recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/) is one of the popular choices and easy to implement. You could follow [this guide](https://codeforgeek.com/google-recaptcha-tutorial/), it seems reasonable, although i haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I was told the bots just scan the code and skip the captcha and go straight to the action end URL.

Comment: Have you read the guide? It's easily done within 1 day (actually even less) but im just offering you the advice that if you dont have the experiece of google recaptcha then its a good time to invest 1 day into it to see its advantages/disadvantages. It'll serve you well in the future. Theres also google recaptcha v3 which requires no user interaction. Its kinda hard to admin that but you can try it out too. - Some client having 10 requests per second which last less than 1 second, google can recognise that as a bot. And tell you that you shouldnt execute that script.

Comment: *"I was told the bots just scan the code and skip the captcha and go straight to the action end URL."* While that might be true or not. If someone would be determined to annoy you, s/he would do it personally, at which point you cant really protect yourself very efficiently. You might even consider renting services that protect you against that, but there is also that question of how much money you have at your disposal. Google offers a free and good enough solution to protect at least against most of the annoying bots. Which is already a lot in my opinion and worth the time investment.

Comment: Thanks. I read about recaptcha and it seems recaptcha v2 invisible would be the best option. I am trying atm Johan javascript method and no spam emails have been added during 24h. If they still keep coming later then I will add recaptcha v2 invisible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to prevent this would be to implement some sort of validation like reCAPTCHA: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/

A very simple first step could be to set the action in a JavaScript snippet. Most of these bots do not execute javascript and will try to post to the page the form is on (probably not very future proof, but it has been working since 2005 for me)

In the code below, I have added an id to the form tag, removed the action attribute and added a bit of javascript to set it after page load.

```html
<form id="myform" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey w3-text-blue w3-margin">

  <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="email" input type="email" required placeholder="Enter Your Email Here">
  <input type="hidden" name="campaign_token" value="fhdfh" />
  <input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="https://example.com/confirm-email.php" />
  <input type="hidden" name="start_day" value="0" />

  <div style="margin-top:25px;"><button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-block w3-section w3-deep-orange w3-ripple" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">Send me the eBook on Email</button></div>
</form>

<script>
  document.getElementById('myform').setAttribute('action', 'https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and see if the bot email submits stop :)

Comment: It seems the form id wokaround worked. No new spam mails for 2 days :)

Comment: Great to hear, thanks for the update! Lucky for us, most of these bots are really simple :)